What kind of very tiny bugs are these? Please help to identify!
The are very very tiny, finding number of them in my bathroom and bedroom, Difficult to see on non- white surface. Difficult to click pictures, This is best I can come up with.
Location - MD, USA




Are these bird mites?

That's a good guess based on coloration, etc., but it's hard to imagine why a bird mite would be walking around on its own... I've only ever seen them after handling a bird-in-the-wild.

We had a bird nest just below our bedroom window, I never paid attention, till I found these in my bedroom and started panicking. They must have entered through he cervices' of the window.

If the birds recently fledged, they are probably mites left behind in the empty nest, now looking for a new host. The invasion should disappear soon.
